# Meaning of - "I will mind my row"

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english

I saw the following question in a book.

**Question**: What will you do if the teacher is not in the class?
**Answer** : I am row leader so that's why I will mind my row.

Can you please explain the meaning of "I will mind my row"

Comment: Which book is this? it sounds a very stilted construction.

Comment: The construction sounds very British. Likely the character in your American book is speaking British English, perhaps by affectation.

Comment: Without the reference to being "row leader" I would assume it was a combination of the expressions "mind your own business" and "hoe your own row", which both mean roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mind has many meanings, one of which is:

> "to look after someone, usually on a temporary basis"

The person in your example is saying that, when the teacher is not in class, they will take care of the other students in the same row to which they have been appointed as row leader. Presumably, this would require the row leader to ensure that the other students behave themselves and do whatever work the teacher has set until the teacher returns.

Comment: I'd note that this might be a common role for a student in some countries, but I've never heard of it in British schools.

Comment: @JamesK As an American, this is a foreign concept to me as well and I'm having difficulty finding any references to such a role through Google searches. It makes me rather curious if this is a purely fictional situation or if establishing a "row leader" is actually common practice in some regions and, if so, where.

Answer (score 4):

It most probably goes for *I'll take care of those who sit in the same row as me, so that they won't misbehave and the teacher won't have to tell us off because of it*. Check the definition of **row** in LDOCE (5th edition):

> **row**
>   1. a line of things or people next to each other → column
>   2. a line of seats in a theatre or cinema

Comment: What is the meaning of _mind_ in dictionary in above context?

Comment: @Marcus There's a world where OP doesn't know that expression either and actually needs the definition of mind (= take care of)

Answer (score 1):

At least in British English, a [**minder**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/minder) is

> a person whose job it is to look after someone or something. eg:"a baby-minder"

The Answerer in your example has a duty to make sure the people in their row of desks aren't mis-behaving, deputised from the teacher. So while the teacher is away they'll continue to look after their row.